# Git completion including flags with bash aliases

Tags: git, bash

I have git completion working with my bash aliases

*~/.bash_profile*

```
if [ -f $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion ]; then
  source $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash
fi

alias gco='git checkout'
__git_complete gco _git_checkout
```

How can I do a `__git_complete` for a git command with a flag?

```
alias gcb='git checkout -b'
```

Comment: Look on this code which does the auto completion and add your code there :-) https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash